# Command SetOwnerAndGroup failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i have a problem when i archive my app (Command SetOwnerAndGroup failed with a nonzero exit code)

Answer (score 1):

I would try doing building it while connected to the company VPN.